# can not get input/outputs from DJANGO

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django.While practicing. I downloaded HTML template and managed to modify it to load up with django. my issue that i can not get any inputs or outputs from Django<>HTML.I do not know where is the problem.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'home.html' ,{})

    def contact(request):
        if request.method == "POST" :
            username_1 = request.POST["username"]
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'username_1' : username_1})

login_page/urls.py

    from django.urls import path
    from . import views


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name="home"),

    ]
```

home.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login V1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{%static 'login_page/images/icons/favicon.ico' %}"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'login_page/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'login_page/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'login_page/vendor/animate/animate.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'login_page/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'login_page/vendor/select2/select2.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'login_page/css/util.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'login_page/css/main.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <div class="login100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                    <img src={%static 'login_page/images/img-01.png'%} alt="IMG">
                </div>

                <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post"  >
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        {{ username_1 }}
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder=Username>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>

                    </div>



                    <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">

                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <script src="{%static 'login_page/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src={%static 'login_page/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js' %}"></script>
    <script src={%static 'login_page/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src={%static 'login_page/vendor/select2/select2.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src={%static 'login_page/vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js' %}></script>
    <script >
        $('.js-tilt').tilt({
            scale: 1.1
        })
    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src={%static 'login_page/js/main.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

setting.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'dugwc2(qu!9$til@n(gbeur^5bv76m2l&0j(!muv22k+sf$_9@'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login_page',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'login.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'login.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Folders tree :
[My DJANGO FOLDER TREE SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk0lF.png)

What I am trying to do, is to the username inputs and redirect them to {{ username_1 }} in html.

UPDATE 1 : i modified urls.py and html to the below, and the same issue.

views.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('', views.home, name="contact"),

]
```

html

```
        <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post"  >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <span class="login100-form-title">
                {{ username_1 }}
            </span>
```

#### The solution provided by SahilDesai, worked for me

Comment: You need to add URL for contact view function and then give it inside of form tag action=""

Comment: your contact function is never getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login_page/urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name="home"),
        path('contact/', views.contact, name="contact") # Registering the contact function  
    ]
```

Inside html file

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form" action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post" >
```

passing that name parameter of contact function inside form tag

Comment: Thank yooooou so much, it worked. can you explain to me ?

Comment: you though created form but never mentioned name of the function contact in action parameter. Also, you registered home function in urls.py but not contact function. So, first register contact function in the same way as home function and then mention name parameter inside form tag